# Absolute Value Inequality Problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, solution-verification

> Problem: $\dfrac{2}{|x-4|}>1$ Express the solutions using intervals

My attempt using the Definition of Modulus:
$$\dfrac{2-|x-4|}{|x-4|}>0$$

$$CASE A:x-4\ge 0\Rightarrow x\ge4\Rightarrow x\in [4,\infty) \Longrightarrow |x-4|=x-4 $$ 
$\dfrac{6-x}{x-4}>0$
$$\Longrightarrow x\in (4,6) \cap [4,\infty)\Longrightarrow x\in (4,6)$$
$$CASE B:x-4< 0\Rightarrow x<4\Rightarrow x\in (-\infty,4) \Longrightarrow |x-4|=-(x-4) $$ 
$\dfrac{x-2}{x-4}>0$
$$\Longrightarrow x\in (-\infty,4)\cap[(-\infty,2)\cup(4,\infty)]$$
$$\Rightarrow \in(-\infty,2)$$
Thus, the final solution through this method should be $x\in (4,6)\cup(-\infty,2)$
However, we know that the answer is $x\in(2,6)-${4}
Could somebody please tell me where I've gone wrong? Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Actually the answer is $x \in (2,4) \cup (4,6)$ since the left hand side is not defined at $x = 4$.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry for the error.

Comment: the idea is that in case B , when you have  $|x-4|=-(x-4)$ you have to pay attention also to the denomenator , so you get $$ \frac{2-x}{x-4}>0$$
So I suggest writting  $$ \frac{x-2}{4-x}>0$$ this implies (as $4-x >0$) $$ x-2 >0$$ then  $x \in (2,4)$. Thus for the final answer $x \in (2,6) -\{ 4 \}$

Comment: Oh... Sorry, hadn't noticed that I hadn't changed the denominator. Thanks so much for pointing out my error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case B) when you substitute |x-4|=-(x-4) then this should imply (x-2)/(4-x) not (x-2)/(x-4).
Check it out

Comment: Yes, Sir, I forgot to do that. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Multiply by $|x-4|$ and then read the inequality out loud: “The distance of $x$ to $4$ is less than $2$.” And be aware of that $x=4$ is not a solution.

Comment: Sir, I know how to solve by multiplying both sides by |x-4| (since it is always positive, hence direction of the inequality remains the same). But sir, why is my method yielding a wrong answer?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to consider separate cases. Since $|x-4|$ is not negative you can multiply across without changing the inequality.

You are then solving $|x-4|<2\Rightarrow-2<x-4<2$.
Then you get the solution set you are supposed to get.